# Parametrization of level sets of a smooth function

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, morse-theory

Let $H:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be given by $H(q,p)=p^2/2+3q^2/2$ (single-well potential). This function has a critical point at $(0,0)$. Define $T:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by,

$T(h)=\int\limits_{H^{-1}(h)}\frac{dx}{|\nabla H(x)|}$.

Question: Is $T$ continuous? And if possible can this be shown by the intuitive idea below?

My intuition suggests that I should somehow convert this integral over a level set into an integral over a fixed surface by creating some sort of parametrization of level sets. This seems plausible because $H$ is smooth enough. Searching over internet esp. in Differential Geometry based references I have  found the idea of a tubular neighbourhood (I don't have much background in geometry). Can this be used somehow to convert the integral above to an integral over a fixed domain?

Apologies if the question and the idea is too vague. Would be grateful for any references in this direction as well.

PS. Not too sure about tags for this question.

Comment: It sounds like you want a general approach, e.g. conditions on a function $H$ for $T$ to be continuous? This particular example seems very easy, since $\nabla H$ is constant on each hypersurface.

Comment: Yeah I see your point. So maybe a $H$ whose level sets are not circles but rather ellipsoids. Actually I am trying to simplify the problem here. I am looking at double well potentials for $H$ (possibly in higher dimensions).

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis - Question edited to have level sets which are not circles and thus $\nabla H$ is not constant on hypersurfaces. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a relevant result you can extract from the proof of Theorem
3.1 in Milnor's *Morse Theory*:

> Let $H$ be a smooth real-valued function on a Riemannian manifold $M$ (e.g. $\mathbb R^n$ with Euclidean metric) such
>   that $H^{-1}\left(\left[a,b\right]\right)$ is compact and contains
>   no critical points of $H$. Then there is a unique solution to the
>   modified gradient flow equation 
>   $$
> \psi_{0}\left(x\right)=x,\quad\frac{d\psi_{t}\left(x\right)}{dt}=\frac{\nabla H}{\left|\nabla H\right|^{2}}\bigg|_{\psi_{t}\left(x\right)}\tag{1}
> $$
>   with $\psi_{t}$ sending level sets $H^{-1}\left(h\right)$ to level
>   sets $H^{-1}\left(h+t\right)$ diffeomorphically.

Now let's try to show continuity of $T$ for $H$ satisfying the above
the conditions. We can apply a change of variables to make the domain
of integration fixed: 
$$
T\left(a+t\right)=\int_{\psi_{t}H^{-1}\left(a\right)}\frac{dx}{\left|\nabla H\right|}=\int_{H^{-1}\left(a\right)}\frac{\det\left(d\psi_{t}\left(x\right)\right)}{\left|\nabla H\left(\psi_{t}x\right)\right|}dx.
$$

From here note that $\psi_{t}$ is $C^{1}$ in the $t$ direction
(since $(1)$ says that its $t$ derivative is a continuous function evaluated along
a continuous curve), and thus the Jacobian determinant term is continuous;
and very similarly we have continuity of $\left|\nabla H\circ\psi_{t}\right|^{-1}$.
(Recall throughout that $\left|\nabla H\right|\ne0$.) So the integrand
is continuous in $t$. Since the integrand is continuous on a compact
set $\left[a,b\right]\times H^{-1}\left(a\right)$, we can exchange
limits with integrals (e.g. by the Dominated Convergence theorem) and thus the integral itself is continuous on
$\left[a,b\right]$.

For your example, any $b>a>0$ satisfy the conditions; so $T$ is
continuous on $\left(0,\infty\right)$.

Comment: Thanks very much. This argument was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: As a side question is there also some theory (references etc) which allows one to deal with critical points ($\nabla H(x)=0$) in the context of such problems?

Comment: @UPS: Morse Theory studies how the topology of (sub-)level sets change as you pass critical points; but I'm unsure how to analyse how such an integral over level sets behaves at a critical point. You'd need some reasonably strong conditions to expect continuity - in general there's no reason to expect that the integral over the critical level set will even be finite.